# Sum by groups, preserving NAs

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to aggregate the dataframe in order to have one date per row (for each group).

```
     Cod1       Cod2    Date     E   A       S
327 100013.0    001 2019-02-01  0.0 0.0    511.0
323 100013.0    001 2019-02-01  0.0 -14.0   NaN
336 100013.0    001 2019-02-02  0.0 -28.0   NaN
341 100013.0    001 2019-02-03  0.0 -6.0    NaN
350 100013.0    001 2019-02-03  0.0 -3.0    NaN
373 100013.0    001 2019-02-07  0.0 -15.0   0
377 100013.0    001 2019-02-07  0.0 -9.0    NaN
```

Using the following:

```
df = df.groupby(['Date', 'Cod1', 'Cod2'])['E','A', 'S'].sum()
```

I got the following output:

```
2019-02-01  100013.0    001 0.0 -14.0   511.0
2019-02-02  100013.0    001 0.0 -28.0   0.0
2019-02-03  100013.0    001 0.0 -9.0    0.0
2019-02-06  100013.0    001 0.0 -24.0   0.0
```

My questions is:

- Is there some way to aggregate preserving NaN ?

There will be 3 scenarios:

1 -) Two rows on same date, last column having NaN and a not null number:

```
327 100013.0    001 2019-02-01  0.0 0.0    511.0
323 100013.0    001 2019-02-01  0.0 -14.0   NaN
```

I would like that in this situation always keep the number.

2-) Two rows on same date, last column having 2 NaNs rows

```
341 100013.0    001 2019-02-03  0.0 -6.0    NaN
350 100013.0    001 2019-02-03  0.0 -3.0    NaN
```

I would like that in this situation always keep the NaN.

3-) Two rows on same date, last column having one zero value column and one NaN column

```
373 100013.0    001 2019-02-07  0.0 -15.0   0
377 100013.0    001 2019-02-07  0.0 -9.0    NaN
```

I would like that in this situation always keep the 0.

---

So my expected out should be this one:

```
2019-02-01  100013.0    001 0.0 -14.0   511.0
2019-02-02  100013.0    001 0.0 -28.0   NaN
2019-02-03  100013.0    001 0.0 -9.0    NaN
2019-02-06  100013.0    001 0.0 -24.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `min_count`

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Cod1', 'Cod2'])['E','A', 'S'].sum(min_count=1)
Out[260]: 
                            E     A      S
Date       Cod1     Cod2                  
2019-02-01 100013.0 1     0.0 -14.0  511.0
2019-02-02 100013.0 1     0.0 -28.0    NaN
2019-02-03 100013.0 1     0.0  -9.0    NaN
2019-02-07 100013.0 1     0.0 -24.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess a custom function can do:

```
(df.groupby(['Date', 'Cod1', 'Cod2'])
    ['E','A', 'S']
    .agg(lambda x: np.nan if x.isna().all() else x.sum())
)
```

Output:

```
                            E     A      S
Date       Cod1     Cod2                  
2019-02-01 100013.0 1     0.0 -14.0  511.0
2019-02-02 100013.0 1     0.0 -28.0    NaN
2019-02-03 100013.0 1     0.0  -9.0    NaN
2019-02-07 100013.0 1     0.0 -24.0    0.0
```